# SQL query for removing all completely empty columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to show only columns that have a value somewhere in them. but since my DB contains dozens of columns, I don't want to specify in advance what columns I need. 
I'm looking for a query such as:

```
select * from table_name where column_has_non_null_data_somewhere
```

Example:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed number of columns, defined in the `SELECT` clause.  If you want a variable number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'd consider re-designing the db.

Comment: Can you tell us what your output should look like?

Comment: Just updated an example @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: As others have said, you probably need dynamic SQL if you want to control the columns programatically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to apply it on all columns of the table (meaning I know how many columns there are in the query), I just don't want to specify each one individually...

Comment: @TomerSharon Please upvote the anwser if it worked for you so that others would prefer it

Answer (score 1):

You could try below way of eliminating columns with all empty or null values.

Suppose you have;

```
SELECT * FROM Filter
```

**Output:**

```
A       B       C       D
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    1       NULL    NULL
NULL    1       NULL    NULL
NULL    1       NULL    NULL
1       1       0       NULL
```

**Try:**

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(A) FROM Filter) < 1)
    SELECT B, C, D FROM Filter
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(B) FROM Filter) < 1)
    SELECT A, C, D FROM Filter
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(C) FROM Filter) < 1)
    SELECT A, B, D FROM Filter
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(D) FROM Filter) < 1)
    SELECT A, B, C FROM Filter
```

**Output:**

```
A       B       C
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    1       NULL
NULL    1       NULL
NULL    1       NULL
1       1       0
```

Comment: Hey @Reyan, thank you for your reply. As I mentioned in the original question, I'm looking for a way to apply the filter without specifying the column names, that is because my table has a massive amount of columns.

Comment: Not yet @Reyan.